# HTACCESS - Subdomínio

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, subdomínio

Alguém ai sabe como configurar o htaccess? Preciso que ele funcione com o subdomínio, e que não apareça o domínio principal na barra de endereços, quando o subdomínio estiver aberto.
Ex de como está agora:

> [https://www.site.com.br/www.subdominio.com.br]

O meu htaccess atual é o código abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar colocar isso aqui no `.htaccess` da pasta do subdomínio:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdominio.site.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdominio.site.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com.br/subdominio/$1 [P]
```

No exemplo estou considerando que você tem a pasta `subdominio` na raiz do domínio, ai da pra você editar de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Mano, obrigado. Sua ajuda foi útil demais. Abraços!